# update Joda DateTime object

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Let's say I have a Joda DateTime object, represented by the following pattern
"MMM d, yyyy  / HHmm"

Is there a way to update the DateTime "Day part" or "Time part" independently  from two strings ?

For instance :

```
DateTime aDateTime initial : JAN 1, 1970 / 2230
```

If I have a String `aDayString="FEB 3, 1980"` and a String `aTimeString="1520"`,

- how can I update aDateTime **day** only (to obtain FEB 3, 1980 / 2230) ?
- how can I update aDateTime **time** only (to obtain JAN 1, 1970 / 1520) ?

Comment: as far as I know you cant. DateTime is immutable so you would have to create a new object based on the original DateTime object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joda's [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) objects are immutable, so just like `String`, when you change a value you get a new instance. Therefore:

```
DateTime initial = new DateTime( 1970, 1, 1, 22, 30, 0 );
DateTime dayUpdated = initial.withDate( 1980, 2, 3 );
DateTime timeUpdated = initial.withTime( 15, 20, 0, 0 );
// At this point, initial still contains 1970-1-1, 22:30
//                dayUpdated is 1980-2-3 22:30
//                timeUpdated is 1970-1-1 15:20
```

If you have a very large number of such changes to process and want to reduce garbage collector load, you can use [`MutableDateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/MutableDateTime.html) to have an initial instance that you can directly modify.

```
MutableDateTime mutable = new MutableDateTime( 1970, 1, 1, 22, 30, 0 );
mutable.setDate( 1980, 2, 3 );
mutable.setTime( 15, 20, 0, 0 );
// at this point, mutable contains 1980-2-3 15:20
```

In most common cases, the predictability of having immutable objects beats the benefits of having a mutable instance, so I would recommend taking the first approach.